# Full width bug constraint in auto layout for ios 8 (works in ios 7)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, storyboard, autolayout

I have a blue *(on the screenshots)* UIView that I want to set to full width in Auto Layout using Storyboard.

My settings work perfectly on iOS 7 but not on iOS 8.

When I `println(blueView.frame.size)` on iOS 7, I get the right number : 320 points width. But on iOS 8, I get 600 points width, the same 600 as defined in Storyboard when using **wAny hAny** layout.

`println` is done here :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Some stuff
    println(blueView.frame.size)
}
```

This is what I have done until now :

[image: Blue UIView to set to full width]
[image: Constraint of the UIView]

What I also find strange is that I apply the same kind of constraint to the other elements (UILabel, UIImageView) and they work correctly on iOS 7 and 8. It is just UIViews that do not work correctly.

There is no auto-layout warning in the console.

**Update** : Here is the visual issue

[image: iOS7 vs iOS8]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - what is going wrong in your app? Is it just that the logged value is wrong? And which method are you running `println` in - are you sure that the views have had time to layout beforehand? What exactly is the problem? Finally, if you think you have found a proper bug then please report it to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crazily enough, this behavior can be expected, depending on the timing of your `println` statement.

In iOS 7, the blue view would be laid out the first time at 320 points wide, assuming that its container view would eventually get that width. In iOS 8 with adaptability, however, views created out of storyboards no longer make that assumption; instead, the views are instantiated with the storyboard's canvas size of 600x600pts. The views are later resized during the first runtime Auto Layout pass to have the correct width for your app's window and view controller hierarchy.

I would expect that if your `println` statement occurs in `-awakeFromNib` or `-viewDidLoad`, you'll see this initial 600pt width. However, if you were to move it to `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `-viewDidAppear:`, you would see the width that matches thew window width of whatever device you're running on.

Comment: Great explanations ! This has indeed solved my issue. Thanks a lot !